# WP - conflict with theme files

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm developing a theme and am using two post types. Default posts for Blog and News posts (custom type) for News. When I open News - it uses the proper theme file, but marks the nav bar menu item of Blog. Blog is using home.php (default for general posts). News is using 'category-news.php'. Any ideas why is this clashing?

### UPDATE

`WP_Query Object
(
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [page] => 0
            [news] => blog-2
            [post_type] => news
            [name] => blog-2
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [comments_popup] => 
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [s] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )`

```
        [category__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__not_in] => Array
            (
```

Comment: You can try add `wp_reset_query()` before at your navigation code.

Comment: @FatihSARI Didn't work... can i provide any other relevant info?

Comment: one tip to troubleshoot these kinds of issues is to stick this in your theme file (category-news.php in your case): `<?php print_r($wp_query); ?>`. This will print all the query vars, and inform you exactly what template Wordpress is attempting to load. In case you can't figure it out from there, show us the output by pasting it here or in a pastebin.

Comment: @JPLew - Thanks - here is a dump of what I get. I'm no longer using a category but rather a Page Template to list out all news posts and that works fine. But when I open a specific news post - still marks my default posts page as active instead of the NEWS page. See update above for query dump.

Comment: That isn't the entire dump - just didn't feel the rest is relevant - but if needed, I can add it all. One part that isn't here shows the following: 
`
[query] => Array
        (
            [page] => 
            [news] => blog-2
            [post_type] => news
            [name] => blog-2
        )
`

So basically, it loads everything as it should, but marks my Default Posts Page (set in the Reading settings) as active in the navbar instead of the News page (which is a page template)

Comment: ok go into your page source and search for "active". If you're using Wordpress Menus it will bring up the list item in your navbar which has been activated. Show us that, it should look something like this: `<li id="menu-item-228" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-211 current_page_item menu-item-228 active">`

Comment: Here it is: 
http://www.codeshare.io/GiJsj
It marks the blog active, not news... no idea why as I'm using single.php for blog posts and single-news.php for news posts

Comment: I'm using Roots starter theme which cleans the tags in the navigation btw

Comment: hmmm, hard for me to say without directly looking at your site. I think it has something to do with the fact your news post is labelled `blog-2`. If I had to guess it has something to do with that.

Comment: Noup - tried it. I will post a detailed breakdown if you don't mind looking at it?

Comment: sure, i can't promise anything but I don't mind looking at it

Comment: Didn't really figure out the issue, but was able to 'fix it' - some conflict was there, but no idea what. I'm using Types for the custom post type - so that mixed with the Reading settings (posts page) cause a problem. I removed the Default Post Page in the reading settings, made a page template that queries the posts and now it works... thanks for all your help!